# Need IBM Watson AlchemyLanguage Python SDK Complete samples

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I am trying to find end-to-end sample code for the IBM Watson AlchemyLanguage Python SDK and IBM Watson Retrieve and Rank Python SDK. I do have sample code from each SDK but they are very skeletal (just class / function definitions). I am hoping to find samples where the API is called, files are uploaded and functions are called, e.g. entity, sentiment, text, etc.

Comment: have you tried this http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/getting-started-guide/using-alchemyapi-with-python ?

Comment: Yes I did look there but thank you. I posted a message on Watson's Slack page and they indicate that they are creating an Application Starter Kit for just this purpose.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, glad t know that

Comment: Check back here as I will post when the kit is available and where to find it once I know.

Answer (score 1):

Each SDK has an [`examples`](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/tree/master/examples) folder with examples of how to call the different methods.

- AlchemyLanguage [examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/alchemy_language_v1.py)
- Retrieve and Rank [examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/retrieve_and_rank_v1.py)

There is also a [`resources`](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/tree/master/resources) folder with some example files you can use when calling the APIs.